# Need multiple tableview cells with different rows

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift3, tableview, swift4

I have one table view using a different cell based on what tab you select. It is working,  although the 1st one seems to be controlling the height. I have one row in the first tab but 2 in the second and both just show 1.
I'm wondering if I need to clear dequeueReusableCell on tab select or something like that. Any Ideas?

[image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  if activeTab == "tab1" {
    return someService.tab1.count
  } else {
    return someService.tab2.count
  }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if activeTab == "tab1" {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Tab1Cell") as? Tab1Cell {
        let tab1 = someService.tab1[indexPath.row]
        cell.updateView(tab1: tab1)

        return cell
    } else {
        return Tab1Cell()
    }
} else {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Tab2Cell") as? Tab2Cell {
        let tab2 = someService.tab2[indexPath.row]
        cell.updateView(tab2: tab2)

        return cell
    } else {
        return Tab2Cell()
    }
  }
}
```

I'm also fixing the scroll with this:

```
func fixTableViewSize() {
  let cells = self.notesTable.visibleCells
  var heightOfTableView = 0
  for cell in cells {
    print("cell")
    heightOfTableView += Int(cell.frame.height)
  }
  self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(heightOfTableView)
  self.buttonFromTableTopConstraint.constant = CGFloat(heightOfTableView)
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside `numberOfRowsInSection`.  Check which `return` is being executed and what the content is in the matching data array.

Comment: did you call tableview.reload when you tap tab2?

Comment: Yeah when I tap tab2 I call these self.mainTable.reloadData() self.fixTableViewSize()

Comment: numberOfRows returns correctly, 1 on tab1 and 2 on tab2 for the count

Comment: try to register your table view cell with this code tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Tab1Cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Tab1Cell")